# Formula for Reflection about $y=mx$ axis along $y=\frac{-x}{m}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

> $T $ is a Reflection about $y=mx$ axis along $y=\frac{-x}{m}$ then
>   $T(a,b)=\Big(2(\frac{a+mb}{1+m^{2}})-a,2(\frac{m(a+mb)}{1+m^{2}})-b\Big)\forall 
> (a,b)\in \mathbb{R^{2}}$. How can I derive the Result?

I don't Know How to start analytically. Please help me to find the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the image be $(a^*, b^*)$.  This point as well as the original point $(a, b)$ lie on the a line $L$ with slope $\frac{-1}{m}$ and some intercept (call it $c$).  Solving for $c$, $c=b+\frac{a}{m}$.

Where does $L$ intersect the original line $y=mx$?  At the point

$$(x^*,y^*)=\left(\frac{a+mb}{1+m^2} , m\frac{a+mb}{1+m^2}\right)$$

So, now, you know that the image point must be at $\left(a + 2(x^*-a), b+2(y^*-b)\right)$ which is the point you have.

[image]

Comment: I added a picture to get clarity and instead of writing an answer, I took the liberty to put it into your answer. Hope you don't mind

Comment: Very well done, Satish.  Thank you. I haven't yet figured out typesetting and adding figures yet on stackexchange. Note to original questioner:  Please note that in the figure above lines y=mx and y= -x/m are perpendicular (their slopes tell you that). Satish's figure probably got squished as it got rendered here, but that's how to imagine it.